# Strip trailing characters from path string

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regex and am looking to trim a known number of characters off the end of a string.  The string represents a filepath, so instead of `c:\test\test1\test2`, I would like to strip off the trailing characters leaving `c:\test`.

The trouble that I am having is with the backslashes.

What sort of regex would I use to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions."
>   Now they have two problems.

Since you're dealing with file paths, you can use the methods of the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class to calculate the result:

```
string GetPathFirstLevel(string path)
{
    while (Path.GetDirectoryName(path) != Path.GetPathRoot(path))
    {
        path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    }

    return path;
}
```

This will return the following values:

```
GetPathFirstLevel(@"c:\test\test1\test2")  //  @"c:\test"
GetPathFirstLevel(@"c:\test")              //  @"c:\test"
GetPathFirstLevel(@"c:")                   //  null
```

Comment: Good answer, and I agree that this is the right approach, however, it doesn't answer the question and that is 'using regex how do I do this'

Comment: @dtb - I shared the love also

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: I'd like to point out that Regex isn't really the most appropriate tool for this job, it's more appropriate to use the File.IO API to check for path validity - for which I'll point to @dtb's answer.

**However, in direct answer to your question** without debating the merits of other approaches is this:

The regular expression string used to extract `C:\Test` from `C:\Test\Test\Test\Test` where you want the `[Drive]:\RootFolder` from any given path is:

```
"[a-zA-Z]:\\[^\\]+"
```

[a-zA-Z] gives you any single character in the character range a-z or A-Z, thus covering upper and lower case.

followed by a `:`

followed by `\` (\ is an escape character so it must be escaped to use it - you escape the character by prefixing it with a \ so where you want \ you put \\ - make sense?)

[^\]+ means the remainder of the string up to but not including the next instance of a `\` or any characters after it.

Also, you can use characters 'unescaped' if you wish by preceding the string with an @ symbol outside the quotes, like so:

```
@"[a-zA-Z]:\[^\]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

No sort of regex.  If you know how many characters you wish to remove you simply use substring...

```
//numberOfChars is known...

string result = inputString.Substring(0, inputString.Length - numberOfChars -1);
```

Comment: Correct, but using the Path class is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use string.split() and Path.DirectorySeparatorChar to figure out what to split on.

Answer (score 1):

The `Path` solutions are better but if you still want the regex (for learning reasons) here it is

```
Regex.Replace(@"c:\aaa\bb\c", @"^([^\\]*\\[^\\]*)\\.*", @"$1")
```

To break it down:

```
^      // begins with
(      // start capturing what you want to save
[^\\]* // zero or more characters that are _not_ backslash
\\     // followed by a backslash
[^\\]* // again zero or more characters that are _not_ backslash
)      // stop capturing
\\     // a backslash
.*     // followed by anything
```

Then the `$1` gives the value of the capture (i.e. the text that matched what was in the first parentheses).